# Rails thinks my mundane seed data are filepaths, throws "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-6, seeding

I'm getting this strange error where it throws "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory" even though no filepaths are involved. For example, if my seed data says:

```
users = Seller.create([{
    username: `Firstuser`
}, {
    username: `Seconduser`,
    password: `123`
}
```

and I try to db:setup or db:seed, I'll get the error:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - Firstuser
>
> /Users/mycomputername/projectname-backend/db/seeds.rb:10:in ``'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/projectname-backend/db/seeds.rb:10:in `'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
> `load'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
> `load'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:557:in
> `block in load_seed'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:675:in
> `with_inline_jobs'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:557:in
> `load_seed'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:440:in
> `load_seed'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:331:in
> `block (2 levels) in '
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in
> `eval'
>
> /Users/mycomputername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in
> `'

Just because I've seen it be relevant in previous questions involving this error, here are the gems I've added to the gemfile:

```
gem "jwt"
gem "faker"
gem 'rails-erd', group: :development
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, `'` and `` ` `` do very different things.

A single quote (`'`) is a delimiter for [string literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings), e.g.:

```
users = Seller.create([
  { username: 'Firstuser' },
  { username: 'Seconduser', password: '123'}
])
```

A backtick (`` ` ``) attempts to invoke a [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(computing)) in a subshell and returns its output, e.g.: (see [`` Kernel#` ``](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#60-method))

```
`ruby --version`
#=> "ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]\n"
```